# How do I setup singular and plural routes to the same resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To start off, I don't know if this is a programmer design choice or if there is a rails 'accepted practice' for this scenario.

I want to create a user profile controller, and have it accessible both 'publicly' like: `/users/[user_id/user_name]/profile` and to the authenticated session user like: `/user/profile`.

I also don't know what is the accepted practice for naming this controller, 'Users::Passwords', 'Users::Password', 'User::Password', etc.

Answer (score 0):

> a user profile controller

Don't.

A *profile* is typically born of the `users` controller:

- `users/edit` = "Profile edit"
- `users/show` = "Profile view"

This means that instead of having a separate `profiles` controller, you should be able to get away with using a single `users` controller:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "", only: [:show], path_names: { show: 'profile' } do
    get "user/profile", action: :edit
    match "user/profile", action: :update, via: [:put, :patch]
end


#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action: :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update]

   def edit
      @user = current_user
   end

   def update
      @user = current_user
   end

   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

---

This will give you the following routes:

- `yoururl.com/:id/profile #-> users/show (show profile)`
- `yoururl.com/user/profile #-> users/edit (edit profile)`

If you then used a gem such as [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to populate the `:id` field with a `username`, or `user handle`: **`yoururl.com/jacob/profile`**

---

Something important I forgot to mention;

The reason why you want to keep your `users` controller slim like this is because of how Rails works - [**OOP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Object orientated programming means that everything you do should revolve around objects. This is a common practice amongst intermediate/advanced devs; Rails is based on it by virtue of Ruby's being OOP.

The way Rails works (and, no, you don't *need* to know this, but it certainly helps) is through a programming pattern called [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

[image]

In the case of Rails, your *models* build the *objects* your application needs to run. This is important because when you finally understand that everything you do with your app has to *start* with what object you're looking to interact with, everything from your *controllers* to your *views* fall into place.

Thus, when you asked whether you should have a "user profile controller", the answer comes from whether you have a user profile object. If not, then you don't need the controller.

A `users` controller will be sufficient, granted you use the correct structure with your methods.

Comment: Excellent writeup. To add, the reason I was considering a design that had the profile separate is that the user model was basically the "login" or "auth" model.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for an accepted practice, that is a matter of taste. (and also depends on the context. A company with hundreds of developers just need more rules, some of them make no sense when working only with few or no other developers.) So this is difficult to answer on Stack Overflow.

For me, these use case are very often distinct: 1. when a user asks for her own profile, and edit it. 2. when a user looks at a profile from a different user, or an admin edit the user data of a user. I present different fields and different pages (the user can change her own password). So they are often conceptually different, even when they access the same model object.

Luckily, nobody forces us to have 1:1 relation between model and controller. 
The MVC Pattern even encourage us to have many controllers for a model.
Rails resource oriented style make some things more easy when you have a 1:1 controller-model relation, like doing a `link_to @user.name, @user`. I see the resource oriented style is sometimes  applied to strict. What matters is the user, and the user interface should never be dictated from implementation details of the model.

I typically use two different controller for these use cases, a profile controller only for the own data, and a users controller for the data of other users. The controllers have their own views. If I want to share part of the presentation, I can use partials. Access security is implicit, the user has no chance to see private data or manipulate passwords of other users. Yes, it duplicates some code. On the other hand, I need no  `if current_user == @user` conditions anywhere.

Comment: I actually like this perspective. It still seems there would be more code duplication though than just having to check for the route that led to the controller#action though. I am considering a CurrentUserController solution.